# Query Builder: where-like doesn't add single quotes?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a rather complex SQL query using Laravel query builder, and I believe I might have run into a bug. I would like to confirm so is the case with you first.

This is the faulty code:

```
public function getWordTranslations($word) {
    if (strpos($word, '*') === false) {
        $word .= '%';
    } else {
        $word = str_replace('*', '%', $word);
    }

    return $this->createTranslationQuery()
        ->whereIn('t.NamespaceID', function ($query) use($word) {

            $tertiaryMatches = DB::table('keywords as k')
                ->join('translation as t', 'k.TranslationID', '=', 't.TranslationID')
                ->where('k.NormalizedKeyword', 'like', $word)
                ->where('t.Deleted', '=', 0)
                ->whereNotNull('k.TranslationID')
                ->select('t.NamespaceID');

            $query->select('NamespaceID')
                ->from('keywords')
                ->where('NormalizedKeyword', 'like', $word)
                ->whereNotNull('NamespaceID')
                ->union($tertiaryMatches);

        })->get();
}
```

The `createTranslationQuery` uses `DB` to create a query builder object. I want to filter the original query with an `IN` subquery.

Unfortunately, the subquery generated by the `whereIn` builder does *not* wrap the value held by `$word` with single quotes.

Expected result when `$word = "sample"`:

```
select ... where t.NamespaceID in(
   select NamespaceID 
   from ...
   where NormalizedKeyword like 'sample%'
   ...)
```

Actual result:

```
select ... where t.NamespaceID in(
   select NamespaceID 
   from ...
   where NormalizedKeyword like sample%
   ...)
```

= Major breakage.

This is the exception (apologies for the lack of formatting!):

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union (select
>   `t`.`NamespaceID` from `keywords` as `k` inner join `translation` ' at
>   line 1 (SQL: select `w`.`Key` as `Word`, `t`.`TranslationID`,
>   `t`.`Translation`, `t`.`Etymology`, `t`.`Type`, `t`.`Source`,
>   `t`.`Comments`, `t`.`Tengwar`, `t`.`Phonetic`, `l`.`Name` as
>   `Language`, `t`.`NamespaceID`, `l`.`Invented` as `LanguageInvented`,
>   `t`.`AuthorID`, `a`.`Nickname` as `AuthorName`, `w`.`NormalizedKey`,
>   `t`.`Index`, `t`.`DateCreated`, `t`.`TranslationGroupID`, `tg`.`Name`
>   as `TranslationGroup`, `tg`.`Canon`, `tg`.`ExternalLinkFormat`,
>   `t`.`Uncertain`, `t`.`ExternalID` from `translation` as `t` inner join
>   `word` as `w` on `t`.`WordID` = `w`.`KeyID` inner join `language` as
>   `l` on `t`.`LanguageID` = `l`.`ID` left join `auth_accounts` as `a` on
>   `t`.`AuthorID` = `a`.`AccountID` left join `translation_group` as `tg`
>   on `t`.`TranslationGroupID` = `tg`.`TranslationGroupID` where
>   (`t`.`Latest` = 1 and `t`.`Deleted` = 0) and `t`.`NamespaceID` in
>   ((select `NamespaceID` from `keywords` where `NormalizedKeyword` like
>   laiquendi% and `NamespaceID` is not null) union (select
>   `t`.`NamespaceID` from `keywords` as `k` inner join `translation` as
>   `t` on `k`.`TranslationID` = `t`.`TranslationID` where
>   `k`.`NormalizedKeyword` like laiquendi% and `t`.`Deleted` = 0 and
>   `k`.`TranslationID` is not null)))

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit #1**
If I remove the union instruction, the query works, so I suspect the errors arise due to the fact that I am using a different query builder to the one provided to the `whereIn` method.

Comment: Where do you see that it's not being escaped? The mysql general log, the DBQueryLog?

Comment: `->where('NormalizedKeyword', 'like', "'$word'");` try this

Comment: @aynber I see it in the exception. I will upload a screenshot, if you would like?

Comment: You can use `->whereRaw("NormalizedKeyword like 'sample%'")`.

Comment: @B.Desai; @TheFallen would that not make my code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: I think this is expected behaviour. If it automatically quoted the third $word argument in the line `->where('NormalizedKeyword', 'like', $word);` then you would not be able to reference columns with the third argument. Therefore, string literals must be used in your particular use-case, as B. Desai demonstrates.

Comment: @Leonard, yes that would make it vulnerable. `whereRaw()` accepts as a second parameter an array of bindings, so you can protect the SQL query.

Comment: It is quoting the variables (the error message gets a little wonky, especially with laravel and parameter binding), but the syntax error is coming near your UNION keyword, not your variable. Can you paste the error as text? Sometimes it's easier to read when it's formatted.

Comment: @aynber, I've done so. Also added an observation.

Comment: It might be easier to run that select outside of the query, and then pass the results into the translation query.

Comment: @aynber Yeah, I just did that. I tried to replace `DB::select` with `$query->newQuery()` but the behaviour is the same. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: what is conclusion of this long discussion? I am facing the same issue in Laravel 8 version. Any suggestion?, will be appreciated. Thanks.